# Wand - How to change and replace an existing image file using Python

Tags: python, wand

I'm trying to distort and replace an existing .jpg image file using wand and python
but I've discovered that I cannot save the modified image using the name of the original.
It seems that the wand save image function only works with a new file name.

Here the code I'm using

```
from wand.image import Image


with Image(filename="C:\\path_to\clock2.jpg") as img:
    img.charcoal(radius=1.5, sigma=0.5)
    img.save(filename="C:\\path_to\clock2.jpg")
```

Now ... the code works if I save using a new file name, for example "C:\path_to\clock2_modified.jpg"

How can I save using the original file name ( thus replacing the original image with the modified one ) ?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can delete old image:

```
import os
os.remove("C:\\path_to\clock2.jpg")
```

before you save modified one

Answer (score 0):

So i'm not entirely sure about your problem here but it seems there is no issue with your code and it is running as you want it to.

I tried running your code on my machine and it takes an existing image, modifies it, and overrides the image. And I'm assuming that is what you are looking for.

Just make sure you are using the latest version of wand, and also please make sure you have **freetype imagemagick** installed.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and helpful suggestion. I'll check the version of imagemagick.. FYI ... I can achieve what is needed ( replacing the file while keeping it's name ) by using os.remove the origional file ... followed by os.remame the modified file name to the origional file name. But that is clunky and not very nice python code.